# Avoiding clashing of events by comparing their time and venues

Tags: php, forms, date, time

This might be easy for some of you but for me its a big hitch:
What I want to do is make sure two events don't clash by comparing their dates and venues.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
<?php
    require_once (LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
    require_once ('../includes/initialize.php');

    class Event extends DatabaseObject {

        protected static $table_name="event_tbl";

        protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'visible', 'event_title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'venue', 'event_type', 'event_description', 'event_program', 'reminder_date', 'reminder_time');

        public $id;
        public $event_title;
        public $start_date;
        public $end_date;
        public $start_time;
        public $end_time;
        public $venue;
        public $event_type;
        public $event_description;
        public $event_program;
        public $visible;        
        public $reminder_date;
        public $reminder_time;



        public function avoid_clash($time1, $time2, $database_venue, $time3, $time4, $venues) {
        $timeStart = strtotime("{$time1}");
        $timeEnd   = strtotime("{$time2}");
        $time      = strtotime("{$time3}") - strtotime("{$time4}");

        if ($result =($time > $timeStart && $time < $timeEnd) && $database_venue==$venues) {
            $session->message('Warning: This event clashes with another!');
            redirect_to('event_management.php');
        }
    } 

    }



    /*function process_avoid_clash($time1, $time2, $time3, $time4, $venues) {
        $event = self::find_from_event();
        $row = fetch_array($event);

        foreach ($row as $rows) {
            $time1 = $rows['start_date']." ".$rows['start_time'];
            $time2 = $rows['end_date']." ".$rows['end_time'];
            $database_venue = $rows['venue'];

            if ($time1 && $time2 && $database_venue) {
                avoid_clash($time1, $time2, $time3, $time4, $venues);
            } else {
                 die("find_from_event failed!");
            }
        }
    }*/



?>
```

Then this is how I test it by using a form which when submitted will alert the user if two events clashed:

```
<?php

    require_once ('../includes/initialize.php');


    if(!$session->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $event = new Event();
        $even = Event::find_public();

                $time3  = $_POST['start_date']." ".$_POST['start_time'];
                $time4  = $_POST['end_date']." ".$_POST['end_time'];
                $venues = $_POST['venue'];

         foreach($even as $events):
                $time1  = $events->start_date." ".$events->start_time;
                $time2  = $events->end_date." ".$events->end_time;
                $database_venue = $events->venue;

                if ($time1 && $time2 && $database_venue) {
                 $event->avoid_clash($time1, $time2, $database_venue, $time3, $time4, $venues);
                }       
                endforeach; 



        $event-> event_title       = $_POST['event_title'];

        $event-> start_date        = $_POST['start_date'];

        $event-> end_date          = $_POST['end_date'];

        $event-> start_time        = $_POST['start_time'];

        $event-> end_time          = $_POST['end_time'];

        $event-> venue             = $_POST['venue'];

        $event-> event_type        = $_POST['event_type'];

        $event-> event_description = $_POST['event_description'];

        $event-> event_program     = $_POST['event_program'];

        $event-> visible           = $_POST['visible'];

        $event-> reminder_date     = $_POST['reminder_date'];

        $event-> reminder_time     = $_POST['reminder_time'];

        $event->create();
        $session->message('Event successfully created!');
        redirect_to('event_management.php');


    }



?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<title>New Event</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../anytime/anytime.css"/>

<script src="../anytime/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../anytime/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>

<script src="../anytime/anytime.js"></script>
<link href="../assets/css/test_project.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="../assets/css/links.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>



<body>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">

    <div class="logo"></div>

    <div class="menu">

   <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul id="navlist">
        </ul>

   </div>

 <br class="clear"/>

   </div>

    <br class="clear"/>

  </div> 

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="sidebar1"> 
    <p><?php echo output_message($message); ?></p>

      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="new_event.php">

        <table width="578" height="322" border="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>

            <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Event Title:</td>

            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="event_title" /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

             <td width="3" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

            <td width="89" align="center" valign="top"><input name="start_date" type="text" size="14" id="start_date" value="START DATE"/></td>

            <td width="60" align="center" valign="top"><input name="start_time" type="text" size="8" id="start_time" value="TIME"/></td>

            <script>

                AnyTime.picker("start_date",

                {format: "%Y-%c-%e"});

                $("#start_time").AnyTime_picker(

                { format: "%H:%i", LabelTitle: "Time",

                labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minute" });

            </script>

            <td width="54" align="center" valign="top"><strong>TO</strong></td>

            <td width="71" align="center" valign="top"><input name="end_date" type="text" size="14" id="end_date" value="END DATE"/></td>

            <td width="74" align="center" valign="top"><input name="end_time" type="text" size="8" id="end_time" value="TIME"/></td>

            <script>

                AnyTime.picker("end_date",

                {format: "%Y-%c-%e"});

                $("#end_time").AnyTime_picker(

                { format: "%H:%i", LabelTitle: "Time",

                labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minute" });

            </script>

            <td width="67" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

            <td width="142" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Venue:</td>

            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="venue" /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Event Type:</td>

            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="event_type" /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td height="59" colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Event Description:</td>

            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="event_description"></textarea></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td height="51" colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Event Program: </td>

            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="event_program"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24" colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Visible:</td>
            <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><input name="visible" type="radio" value="0" />
            No &nbsp;
            <input name="visible" type="radio" value="1" />
            Yes</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td height="40" colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">Reminder:</td>

            <td align="left" valign="top">

              <input name="reminder_date" type="text" size="10" id="reminder_date" /> </td>

            <td align="left" valign="top">

              <input name="reminder_time" type="text" size="10" id="reminder_time"/></td>

            <script>

                AnyTime.picker("reminder_date",

                {format: "%Y-%c-%e"});

                $("#reminder_time").AnyTime_picker(

                { format: "%H:%i", LabelTitle: "Time",

                labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minute" });

            </script>             

            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40" colspan="3" align="right" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Event" /></td>
            <td height="40" align="left" valign="top"> <input name="New" type="button" id="New" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='event_management.php'"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </form> 
       </div>
  <?php include_layout_template('footer.php'); ?>
```

Any information or suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: ...and the problem is?

Comment: Decoding these two not-that-short listings just to guess waht is being asked is frustrating. Please elaborate concerning the concept, the use case, the expected result and the conclusion that the followed procedure fails.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with @geo. If a question reads *"Hi, I'm trying to do X, here's `code code code code code code code code code code code code` and here's more `code code code code code code code code code code code`, please help me"* I don't even bother reading the code. Try to express what you want us to do in English first, then add the code necessary.

Comment: I am so sorry for the time it took you to go through my code without a definite question, I was in a haste to meet my deadline. Was able to figure out the problem; I was subtracting end date from start date and sending the result into the function avoid_clash, instead of the reverse, so I ended up not getting what I wanted from the function which is to give an error message when an event clashes with another.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to push this problem down to your database. PostgreSQL, for example, has great support for this kind of problem as documented in [this blog post](http://www.depesz.com/2010/01/03/waiting-for-8-5-exclusion-constraints/):

> On 7th of December, Tom Lane committed patch by Jeff Davis that adds general exclusion constraints:
>   Log Message:
>   Add exclusion constraints, which generalize the concept of uniqueness to
>   support any indexable commutative operator, not just equality.  Two rows
>   violate the exclusion constraint if "row1.col OP row2.col" is TRUE for
>   each of the columns in the constraint....This could be used for example for making sure that given room is only reserved by 1 user at any give point in time.

as well as a handy ["Temporal" extension](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/temporal) (see [here](http://www.pgcon.org/2012/schedule/attachments/247_Temporal%3a%20Past,%20Present,%20and%20Future) for a slide-deck from PgCon 2012 discussing some of its features).